# Getting validated values on next page in php

Tags: php

I have created one .php file with form fields. I have also validated it in same page. But now, i want all those validated values on next page to be shown in proper format. As I am beginner in php, i don't want to use database or session or cookies concepts. Would it be possible? How?

Comment: so validate it with the other php file

Comment: `<form action="yournextpage.php" method="post"></form>` you can use `$_POST` in that page!

Comment: but after using action attribute, the form is not validating and i am redirected to my next page.

Comment: Well then your “validation” (for which you have not shown us any code) is flawed.

Comment: you can validate it in next page,else if you want to validate in same page you have to use `javascript` or `Jquery`

Comment: can you please tell me php validation?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate fields in the next page directly. In the form action of the first page set the URL of the next page and validate form on it.

If you need to have a third page with more fields, the best solution I think is to use PHP session variables or Javascript to save form fields on window.sessionStorage. You can pass values of a previous page by putting it on hidden fields in this hypothetical case, but I think this is not a clean solution.

The advantage of use PHP session variables is that if the user clicks back button or forward button, or even if the user closes the tab but not de explorer, the variables still remain in session, but if you pass variables through pages via GET or POST this could not happen.

You must not be afraid of using session variables, one way or another in the future probably you need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

option 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function samp()
{

//do validation here
}
</script>
<form action="yournextpage.php" method="post" onSubmit="func2()"></form>
```

option 2

use jquery like this

```
<form action="yournextpage.php" method="post" >

<input type="submit" name="btn" id="idn" value="Click"/>

</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

$("#idn").click(function(e){

// do validation
});
```